# How to export graphics2d To PDF using PDFCLown library

Tags: graphics2d, pdfclown

I am new to pdfClown. I have a Graphics2D data from my JAVA JCanvas i need to export this graphics2d data to PDF. How can i do that by using pdfclown? Please Help me.

Comment: i have tried the sample examples and have seen IContentContext.render (graphics2d, dimension2d) but this method renders the given pdf will it to reverse graphics2d to pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, PDF Clown provides no adapters to translate Graphics2D calls into PDF: AFAIK, iText supports that.

Comment: That's correct: iText has a class `PdfGraphics2D` that extends `Graphics2D`. see [some questions and answers on StackOverflow about iText and `Graphics2D`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext+graphics2d)

Comment: thanks. I already implemented this in  itext 4.2.0 but in itext there is a problem with local languages because i text 4.2.0 not supports indian languages like telugu tamil hindi etc.... so i had look in pdfclown . once again thanks i got my answer.